# DatagridView CheckBox checking returns FormatExceptiion

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview

I browsed a lot on StackOverflow and all over the internet but couldn't find anything that could help me. I am putting some information from a SQL database onto a DataGridView, and i am adding an extra column with checkboxes.

```
private void populatedataGrid()
{
  String sql = "SELECT pm.Name, pm.telephone, pm.email, pm.validID, comp.name as `Company` FROM `project managers`as pm JOIN `companies`as comp ON pm.Companies_companyID = comp.companyID where pm.Companies_companyID =" + loginID;
  MySqlCommand command = new MySqlCommand(sql, dh.Connection);
            
  try
  {
    MySqlDataAdapter adapter = new MySqlDataAdapter();
    adapter.SelectCommand = command;
    DataTable dbdataset = new DataTable();
    adapter.Fill(dbdataset);
    BindingSource bSource = new BindingSource();
                
    // DataGridView1 is a different DataGrid, i am working on DataGridView2
    bSource.DataSource = dbdataset;
    dataGridView1.DataSource = bSource;
    dataGridView2.DataSource = bSource;
    //Method for adding the additional column with checkboxes (ill paste the method below)
    addCheckBoxColumn();
    //I make it so that only the checkboxes can be edited
    foreach (DataGridViewColumn dc in dataGridView2.Columns)
    {
      if (dc.Index.Equals(5))
      {
        dc.ReadOnly = false;
      }
      else
      {
        dc.ReadOnly = true;
      }
    }
    adapter.Update(dbdataset);
  }
  catch (Exception ex)
  {
    MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
  }
  finally
  {
    dh.Connection.Close();
  }
}
```

Here is the method for creating the column with Checkboxes:

```
private void addCheckBoxColumn()
{
  DataGridViewCheckBoxColumn cbCol = new DataGridViewCheckBoxColumn();
  cbCol.ValueType = typeof(bool);
  cbCol.Name = "Select";
  cbCol.HeaderText = "Select";
  dataGridView2.Columns.Add(cbCol);
}
```

And it all works fine for now:
[image: DataGridView]

I created a button for testing purposes, which i want when clicked to write the number of rows that have a checked checkBox on label2.

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  int counter = 0;
  foreach (DataGridViewRow row in dataGridView2.Rows)
  {
    if (Convert.ToBoolean(row.Cells[5].Value))
    {
      counter++;
    }
  }
  label2.Text = counter.ToString();
}
```

When i run it and click Button1 i get the following Exception:

> "An unhandled exception of type 'System.FormatException' occurred in mscorlib.dll
>
> Additional information: String was not recognized as a valid Boolean."

Can you give me some help on how to fix this. I wrote a similar thread half an hour ago when I had a different problem but it got Duplicated so I tried to change my code and now I get this.

Comment: Provide the actual exception.  Include the stack trace.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The column index isn't what you think it is.  Use the name instead:

```
if (Convert.ToBoolean(row.Cells["Select"].Value)) {
  ...
}
```

Your grid has a data source but when you add the CheckBox column to the grid, it's not a part of the data source.  That could mess up the index values of your columns.  Running your code on my computer actually ended up having the CheckBox column with an index of zero, despite appearing as the last column.

Comment: This is indeed true, thank you for pointing that out. I fixed it, but sadly I still get the same exception. I made a screenshot so you could maybe see better. http://i.imgur.com/Gn2M2OF.png

Comment: @KonstantinHadzhiev What's the value of that cell when you get the error?  I recreated your error and it went away when I applied my fix.

Comment: As you probably saw in the screenshot above, my actual datagrid has 2 rows, and i have checked the checkBoxes on both rows, so in theory the counter should be equal to 2. I guess i`m missing something, and its been bugging me for the past 4 hours.

Comment: @KonstantinHadzhiev Not sure why you ignored my question.  Highlight the `row.Cells["Select"].Value` text and see what the value is when the error is thrown.

Comment: Ok...now i decided to close and reopen visual studio and guess what. It works like a charm! Thank you kind sir for all the help!